# Count content in years month archive using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to print the count of news per year/month like this:

2013

- Octobr (20)
- November (45)
- September (80)

2014

- January (5)

I have this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS YEAR, 
                MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS MONTH, 
                COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 
         FROM NEWS GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH";
 $newsdata = DataAccess::ArrayFetch($sql);

 foreach($newsdata AS $news){            
   //what???   
 }
```

Now, how do print years and months?

Comment: What kind of question is this? You print the years and months with `echo $news['YEAR']` and `echo $news['MONTH']`. Is there more to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort them in the query, then you print them in that order. You'll need to detect year changes, to print the year header:

```
$sql = "SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS YEAR, 
                MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS MONTH, 
                COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 
         FROM NEWS GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTH ";
$newsdata = DataAccess::ArrayFetch($sql);

$currentYear = null;

foreach($newsdata AS $news){            
  if ($currentYear != $news['YEAR']){
    echo '<h2>'.$news['YEAR'].'<h2>';
    $currentYear = $news['YEAR'];
  } 
  echo '<dd>'.$news['MONTH'].'<dd><dt>'.$news['TOTAL'].'</dt>';
}
```