# Advanced news archive Years/Month using PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I insert date of news with `timestamp` in `MySQL` database. Now I need to advanced archive for my news Like This :

```
2013

    July (4)
         News 1 
         News 2 
         News 3 
         News 4 
    December (2)
         News 1 
         News 2 
    NovemberPrint (4)
         News 1 
         News 2 
         News 3 
         News 4 
2014
    January (8)
         News 1 
         News 2 
         News 3 
         News 4 
         News 5 
         News 6 
         News 7 
         News 8
```

Now I need any `PHP function` and `MySQL SELECT` structure for print this using PDO Or MySQL Query.

Online Example [HERE](http://www.julienallart.me/archives)

**EDIT:** I found This Ask From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938179/count-content-in-years-month-archive-using-php):

```
$sql = "SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS YEAR, 
                MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS MONTH, 
                COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 
         FROM NEWS GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTH ";
$newsdata = DataAccess::ArrayFetch($sql);

$currentYear = null;

foreach($newsdata AS $news){            
  if ($currentYear != $news['YEAR']){
    echo '<h2>'.$news['YEAR'].'<h2>';
    $currentYear = $news['YEAR'];
  }
 echo '<dd>'.$news['MONTH'].'<dd><dt>'.$news['TOTAL'].'</dt>';
}
```

But, This Print Only Count and GROUP By Years ad Month. I need to listed article after each month.

Comment: I need a lot too! but what have you did to resolve you problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use GROUP BY if you also want the names of the individual articles.  Simply fetch the entire list and then group into an array by year and month.

```
$sql = "SELECT timestamp, your_id_column, your_title_column FROM `NEWS` ORDER BY timestamp DESC";

$newsdata = DataAccess::ArrayFetch($sql);

$nav = array();

foreach ( $newsdata as $news ) {
    $year = date('Y', $news['timestamp']);
    $month = date('F', $news['timestamp']);
    $nav[$year][$month][$news['your_id_column']] = $news['your_title_column'];
}
```

When you iterate the resulting array you can count the news items for each year/month to generate the total.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ( $nav as $k => $v ) {
        ?>
        <li><?php echo $k ?>
            <ul>
            <?php
            foreach ( $v as $k2 => $v2 ) {
                ?>
                <li><?php echo $k2.' ('.sizeof($v2).')' ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php
                        foreach ( $v2 as $k3 => $v3 ) {
                            ?>
                            <li><?php echo $v3 ?></li>
                            <?php   
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use MySQL for this:

```
ORDER BY DATE(actionTime)
```

Just order the results by date instead of grouping them, and replace your count(*) with just a *.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
SELECT YEAR(creation_date), MONTH(creation_date), COUNT(id) from news GROUP BY YEAR(creation_date), MONTH(creation_date)
```